# Geometric Sum Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

In the textbook I'm working from, the formula for the sum of a geometric progression is given as

$S^n=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$

It then adds that the formula may also be written as

$S^n=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$

...if $r>1$

I can't work out why we would require $r>1$ to simply multiply the formula by $\frac{-1}{-1}$. Obviously we need $r\neq 1$ but that's true in both cases, not just the alternate form. Could someone shed some light on this, or else just confirm this is a mistake?

Comment: Both versions of the formula can be used, but when $r > 1$, the second version is easier to use, since both the numerator and denominator will be positive.

Comment: Ahh, so it's just stating that the second form is more convenient when $r>1$, not that it's a condition?

Comment: $r>1$ is also allowed on the condition that the geometric series is NOT an infinite series. If you add up an infinite amount of terms, then $r$ must be strictly less than $1$. As noted above both of the formulas represent the same irrespective of the choice of $r$